# Using auth_redirect returns cannot modify header information

Tags: actions, wp-head

I'm hooking `auth_redirect` to `wp_head`, but it's returning cannot modify header information.  Do I have to hook it to a different action?  Something that loads before wp_head? I tried hooking it to get_headers and send_headers, but then it didn't even work.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
add_action('wp_head','check_if_logged_in');


function check_if_logged_in() {
  $pageid = get_option('sd_page_id');
  if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_page($pageid) ) {
      auth_redirect();
  }
}
```

Also, to clarify, for some reason it works in localhost but not on my server.  Weird.

Comment: Could you post the exact function that you are using to hook auth_redirect?

Comment: Ok added code in my original post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works fine on my localhost as well.

The reason it probably doesn't work on your server is that it's not using [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering).  Hooking into `wp_head` means that the page has already started printing to the client's screen.  Meaning `auth_redirect`'s use of `wp_redirect` will fail: the headers have already been sent and you see the "headers already sent" error.

Try hooking into `template_redirect` instead of `wp_head`.  I wouldn't use `auth_redirect` here either.  You're already checking if the user is logged in (which `auth_redirect` does as well).  Simply sent users to the login page with an appropriate "redirect_to" argument if they aren't logged in.

```
<?php
add_action('template_redirect','wpse64899_check_if_logged_in');
function wpse64899_check_if_logged_in()
{
    $pageid = 2; // or whatever you want it to be
    if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_page($pageid))
    {
        $url = add_query_arg(
            'redirect_to',
            get_permalink($pagid),
            site_url('wp-login.php')
        );
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha! That solved it. Is there a reason why you wouldn't use auth_redirect though?  Just curious.  Thanks!

Comment: `auth_redirect` does the user logged in checking for you as well.  If you're going to use it, there's no need to check of the user is logged in first. `if(is_page($your_page)) { auth_redirect(); }` It's also a pluggable function.

Comment: Oh ok I see.  Got it!

Comment: @chrisguitarguy thanks a lot for the explanation. Just learned the `template_redirect` thing in WordPress, and learned why `wp_redirect()` was showing "headers already sent". Thanks a lot for the explanation.